# Java object teardown pattern

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

Is there any standard way/pattern to extract piecemeal information from an object ? Say I have a json string which contains few classes which I have to extract. I cannot directly extract it using jackson because there are few transformations that need to be done in order to get the required information (like decryption, uncompression etc..) and I am trying to see if I can hide all of these behind a class.

Here is how I am planning on doing it, is there a better way to achieve this ? just wanted an opinion.

```
public class ExtractInformation {
    private final Object1 obj1;
    private final Object2 obj2;
          ....
    private final Object3 objn;

    public ExtractInformation(String jsonString) {
        // Extract all the information here and store locally
        obj1 = ...;
        objn = ...;
    }

    public getObect1() {
        return obj1l;
    }

    public getObject2() {
        return obj12;
    }
           ...
    public getObjectn() {
        return obj1n;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe just try to use HashMap - json can be presented as dictionary, so you can transform `jsonString` ("key:val,key:val") into a map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would more or less agree, just by doing this this way you connect inseparably your domain class (which should not be named ExtractInformation!!!) with the way its data are stored in the json string. You may create 2 separate classes: MyClass (POJO, your domain class) and MyClassJsonExtractor (the class which will serve as a factory for MyClass). And use the [Builder](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/07/builder-design-pattern-in-java.html) pattern for MyClass creation.

```
public class MyClass {
    private final Object1 obj1;
    private final Object2 obj2;
    private final Object3 obj3;

    private MyClass(MyClassBuilder builder) {
        this.obj1 = builder.obj1;
        this.obj2 = builder.obj2;
        this.obj3 = builder.obj3;
    }

    public getObj1() { return obj1; }
    public getObj2() { return obj2; }
    public getObj3() { return obj3; }

    public static class Builder {
        private final Object1 obj1;
        private final Object2 obj2;
        private final Object3 obj3;

        public Builder() {}

        public Builder setObj1(Object1 obj1) {this.obj1 = obj1; return this; }
        public Builder setObj2(Object2 obj2) {this.obj2 = obj2; return this; }
        public Builder setObj3(Object3 obj3) {this.obj3 = obj3; return this; }

        public MyClass build() {
            return new MyClass(this);
        }
    }

}

public class MyClassJSonExtractor {
    // make the as singleton, either by the old-fashioned way or by Spring
    public MyClass createMyClass(String jsonString) {
         return new MyClass.Builder().
             setObj1(...).
             setObj2(...).
             setObj3(...).
             build();
    }
}
```